# ¿Cómo obtener la última fecha de actualización de Windows con PowerShell en formato string?

Tags: powershell

Estoy intentando obtener la última fecha de actualización de Windows desde PowerShell, y quiero guardarla en una variable de Windows a modo texto, para poder usarla en futuras declaraciones.

He intentado este método, que se puede encontrar en diversos foros y tutoriales. Sin embargo, lo guarda en tipo Objeto, y no se pueden sustraer X número de caracteres de él.

```
(New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Results|fl
```

Quiero poder extraer ciertos caracteres del texto imprimido tras esa orden, u obtener directamente sólo la fecha para poder usarla en una declaración de texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### A continuación te explico como puedes hacerlo paso a paso

**1** - Accede al valor que buscas:

```
$lastUpdate = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate
```

De esta manera has creado una variable que devuelve la fecha de la ultima instalación.

```
$lastUpdate
>> martes 16 marzo 2021 08:23:13 AM
```

Pero el contenido de la variable `lastUpdate` es aun de tipo DateTime y no de tipo String.

```
$lastUpdate.GetType().Name
>> DateTime
```

**2** - Para convertirlo a string debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
$lastUpdateSTR = $lastUpdate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Si verificamos la variable y veremos que se convirtió correctamente.

```
$lastUpdateSTR
>> 2021/03/16

$lastUpdateSTR.GetType().Name
>> String
```

Nota que `ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` te permite especificar el formato.

```
"yyyy - MM - dd"
>> 2021 - 03 - 16

"yy - MMM - dddd"
>> 21 - mar - martes

"yyyy - MMMM - ddd"
>> 2021 - marzo - mar
```

---

### En conclusión lo que buscas puede hacerse con esta línea

```
$lastUpdate = (New-Object -com "Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate").Results.LastInstallationSuccessDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Devuelve la string:

```
$lastUpdate
>> 2021/03/16
```

Comment: Gracias. Respuesta muy útil, bien explicada y documentada. Me ha funcionado.